# R: how to combine the same rows as columns A and B of three dataframes, and add the corresponding C column

Tags: r

I have some dataframes, I want to merged them if their first two columns are identical, and add the corresponding third column.
For example, I have three dataframe as follows:

```
> dump1
 a  b c
 q 12 2
 w 23 3
 e 34 4
> dump2
 a  b c
 q 12 1
 w 23 1
 s  3 1
> dump3
 a  b c
 q  2 6
 w 23 7
 s  3 8
 d  2 9
```

Now,I want to get the merged dataframe:

```
> dump5
 a  b  c
 d  2  9
 q  2  6
 s  3  9
 q 12  3
 w 23 11
 e 34  4
```

The data is very big, so I want to have a quikly way.
How to do it? Anybody knows? 
Appreciate in advance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We place the datasets in a `list`, `rbind` it with `rbindlist` from `data.table`, grouped by 'a' and 'b', get the `sum` of 'c'

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(dump1, dump2, dump3))[, .(c = sum(c)), .(a, b)]
```

If there are many datasets with object names start with `dump` followed by numbers created in the global environment, instead of specifying the object names individually, we can use `ls` with `pattern` to get the object names, and then values with `mget` in a `list`,

```
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "dump\\d+")))[, .(c= sum(c)), .(a, b)]
```